# Boolean NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(***Unity3d***)
I'm getting this error related to the **"if(raytest.obstacleExists==true)"**
Here's the main script:

```
private Raytest raytest;

void Start()
{
    target = new Vector3(5f, 0f, 0f);
    obTarget = new Vector3(obstacle.transform.position.x - 1.3f, 0f, 0f);
    raytest = GetComponent<Raytest>();
}

public void Movement()
{
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    //if there is an obstacle ahead
    //stop 1-2 meters before him
    //else
    //go to target position

    if(runCode==true)
    {
        if(raytest.obstacleExists==true)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, obTarget, step);
        }

        else
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, step);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows why is this happening?

Comment: There is no such thing as a boolean null reference.

Comment: As @00110001 mentioned boolean is a value type, so you cannot get boolean null reference exception, the problem might be you **private Raytest raytest;** is not instantiated or referred to any object. You might want to provide more information about the error as it hard to figure out what's the exact problem with our code

Comment: `GetComponent` "*Returns the component of Type type if the game object has one attached, null if it doesn't.*"

Answer (score 1):

raytest seems to be not instantiated. Check if your variable is null or not.

```
if(raytest?.obstacleExists==true)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, obTarget, step);
}
```